# T-SQL SQL Server: Compare todays with future date in IF condition

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime

I need to compare todays date with a future date using IF conditional in T-SQL SQL Server. It is contained in a store procedure which is called from C#. Also I want to return no rows if current date is not less or equal than future date.

So I have done:

```
DECLARE @FutureDate VARCHAR  = '2017-05-20 00:00:00'
IF CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) <= CAST(@FutureDate AS DATE)
BEGIN
   ....
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 0 NULL
END
```

I call this store procedure from C#, But it is generating an error saying cannot convert into datetime. Time is not important for me, only date is important.

**UPDATE**:

Doing this is working and no need to convert FutureDate as DATE.

```
DECLARE @FutureDate DATE  = '2017-05-20'
IF CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) <= @FutureDate
BEGIN
  ....
```

Comment: declare the variable as a datetime or date?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: `DECLARE @FutureDate AS DATETIME = '2017-05-20 00:00:00'` will help in your case.

Comment: `select CAST('2017-05-20T00:00:00.000' AS DATEtime)` ISO 8601 for T-SQL datetime

Comment: @Arulkumar Time is not necessary in my case as I only want to compare dates. Using DATE as posted in my update is enough for me and works.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is working and no need to convert FutureDate as DATE.

```
DECLARE @FutureDate DATE  = '2017-05-20'

IF CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) <= @FutureDate
BEGIN
  ....
END
ELSE
  ....
END
```